# How to Convert Byte Array to Char in C++

Tags: c++, arduino

I don't know how to write a code that convert a byte array to a char array in C++ (using an Arduino board) and publish mqtt. I tried to search but I don't understand.

**Example**

```cpp
byte Code[3] = {0x00 ,0x01 , 0x83};
char byteTochar[3];
    
for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    Serial.printf("%d", Code[i]);
    Serial.println();
    
    client.publish("publish/data", byteTochar[i]);
}
```

**Error message**

```
converting to 'String' form initializer list would use explicit constructor 'String::String'(unsigned char, unsigned char)'
```

Comment: This is not `C`, i guess.

Answer (score 4):

Its actually do c, ArduinoPlayGround  http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/Printf.

However, you can just use casting for each element:

```
char h = (char)Code[i];
```

Comment: sorry i don't understand use byte h = (byte)Code[i]; for convert to char array ?

Comment: My bad, i changed it. do it for each of the array elements throug a loop and youll get an array of byte. Or you can just convert right before passing the argument.

Comment: Thank answer, i will to try :)

Comment: i try write code for apply data not work, console not show data message.

http://pastebin.com/VkbyYg3U

Comment: Please explain what exactly this code should do, cause you passed the wrong params to `itoa` and you didnt use the char, so i dont get what are you trying to do. However, try to initiate the buffer (str) and read this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/